# Screen Recording on Mac is free using QuickTime 10. Is the free solution on Windows using CamStudio?

Tags: screen-recorder, camstudio

On the Mac, we can now record a full screen or part of the screen if you have QuickTime 10 on Snow Leopard or QuickTime 10.1 on Lion.  It is free and it records sound as well.   The video is smooth and in high quality.

What if it is on PC.  Is the standard solution that is free on the PC [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/)?  Is there any reliable alternatives?  I was a little bit worried because CamStudio's website looks like it might be pushing it a little hard, so I am worried about any possibility of adware or malware in it.

Comment: There's absolutely no adware/malware in CamStudio.

Comment: so it is quite credible?  I think the issue with 3rd party app on Windows is that you don't know how much to trust an app